# How to apply OOP technique to Delphi database programming?

Tags: database, delphi, oop, design-patterns, delphi-7

I've been using Delphi for about 10 years to develop database applications.

My everyday life cycle is about creating a new TForm, dropping components such as TSQLQuery, TDataSource (as 2-tier database application) TDBGrid, etc.  Then setting up required properties to display data from the database, and coding CRUD actions according to specific events.

What-if, I would like to use OOP to apply to my everyday life cycle, to make my coding more reusable, I believe, I have a good basic knowledge about OOP, I know how to write classes but in this case U have know ideas what classes I should write, what the class should do.

So Please guide me where to start?  I'm really confusing now for example If I wrote a class for a TCustomer to read data from the database table, after reading from the database how can I give the data to DB Controls such as TDBGrid, so I'm really confusing about what classes to write and what the class should do.

**Edited**
I just wish to have a very simple example let's say if I had to develop a database application which has just one database table (e.g. customers) how to design the pattern or to use oop technique for this application.

Thanks.

P.S. I'm still using Delphi7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1017791/62576 should give you a place to start.

Comment: You should probably study the ORM paradigma. IMHO an interesting description how to redefine a traditional DB approach is in the introductory part of the book [Entity framework in Action](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/). Yes, this is not Delphi, but the principle is similiar. And yes, you'll need some ORM framework: for Delphi there is [TMS Aurelius](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aurelius.asp)

Comment: I just discovered there is some port of Hibernate framework I use in Java [Delphi Hibernate](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

I generally start off with connecting my UdbSrc unit which contains creates a ADOQuery( which can be changed to suit you needs) and then creates a connection string for the component. From there I use queries to perform tasks and load them into objects.

Your example being customers would for example have a name field, possibly age and gender fields as well. So you would create a customer class which encapsulates the previous fields and when you create the object you use the query component to get the information from the database. If you need specific coding just ask and I will put it up.

Hope it helps
Ben :D